# mxgraph how to make edge droppable and insert new vertex between source and target

Tags: mxgraph

How to drag (some draggable in toolbar) on edge and then insert a new vertex between source and target,
I find some examples like [this](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/diagrameditor.html), but  I am not using `mxEditor`, thanks you.

[image]

- https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/diagrameditor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [dropEnabled](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.dropEnabled) and [splitEnabled](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.splitEnabled) properties and call [splitEdge](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.splitEdge) function with target and mouse co-ordinates.